# Proving sequence converges to $0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

PLEASE DO NOT AMSWER OR COMMENT ON THIS QUESTION. I know it's stupid and cannot delete it nor edit it because it's really Stupid. I do not need to be reminded by you!

I need to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n^2+1}=0$$
I applied the definition $\forall\epsilon\gt0$ $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\ge N$ s.t $|L-a_n|\lt\epsilon$.
So $$\Biggl|0-\frac{n}{n^2+1}\Biggr|\lt\epsilon$$
$$\frac{n}{n^2+1}\lt\epsilon$$
But from here I don't know what to do.

Comment: Notice in your statement of the definition, there is an "Exists an $n$ *such that*..." you have started by assuming the conclusion of the "such that", instead of trying to prove it. You need to exhibit a specific $N$, when *given* an arbitrary $\varepsilon$

Comment: Multiply the inequality by $n^2+1$, and solve the quadratic inequality in $n$. This will give/hint at some $N$ for each $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Definition) would say "$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in\mathbb N, \forall n\in\mathbb N\ge N, \ldots$", not "$\ldots \exists n\in\mathbb N\ldots$".

Comment: Note that if $n \gt 0, \frac{n}{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{n+ \frac 1n}$.  The latter form should prove easier to manipulate.

Comment: Why would you not just note that the expression is strictly positive for positive $n$ and is strictly less than $\frac{1}{n}$, and use the squeeze theorem?

Comment: First thing is understanding exactly what the the "for all epsilon there is an $n$ so that the difference is less than epsilon" means, and why you are doing when you say "so I started with the difference is less than epsilon".  The definition is saying that such an $n$ exists.  *You* are saying, "well, if one does, let's find it".  So you are trying to *solve* for $\frac n{n^2 + 1}< \epsilon$.  If such a solution exist your proof is done.  (One thing we can note is that $0 < \frac n{n^2+1} < \epsilon \iff \frac {n^2+1}n > \frac 1\epsilon$)

Answer (score 1):

If you're required to prove this from the definition, first note that for $n \gt 0, \dfrac{n}{n^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{n+ \frac 1n}$.

Choose $\varepsilon \gt 0$.  Let $N$ be an integer greater than $\dfrac {1}{\varepsilon}$.  Then

$$n \gt N \Rightarrow 0 \lt \frac{n}{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{n+ \frac 1n} \lt \frac 1n \lt \frac 1N \lt \varepsilon, \text{ so } \left \vert \frac{n}{n^2+1} - 0 \right \vert \lt \varepsilon.$$

This proves the result.

Or, as noted in the comments you could use the squeeze theorem, which this proof pretty much illustrates.

Comment: Why can you just make the 1/n go away in step 3

Comment: Because $\frac 1n$ is positive so the fraction with the extra $\frac 1n$ in the denominator has a larger denominator than does the next fraction in the chain.  Since the denominator is larger and the numerators are both the same ($1$), the fraction has to be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any given $\varepsilon>0$, the function $f(x)=x^2-\frac{x}{\varepsilon}+1$ is eventually strictly increasing, and, in particular, it is eventually positive. Therefore one can choose a positive integer $N$ large enough such that $f(x)>0$ for every $x>N$, i.e., $f(n)>0$ for every integer $n>N$. Thus $\varepsilon(n^2+1)>n$, i.e., $\frac{n}{n^2+1}<\varepsilon$ for every integer $n>N$.